# Slide toggle in toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to slide toggle my twenty-thirteen mobile menu with slide toggle and it only slide down but it comes back quickly (no slide). I injected other code to make it slide but it is buggy. Here's the original code

```
/**
 * Enables menu toggle for small screens.
 */
( function() {
    if ( ! nav || ! button ) {
        return;
    }

    // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
    if ( ! menu || ! menu.children().length ) {
        button.hide();
        return;
    }

    button.on( 'click.twentythirteen', function() {
        nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        if ( nav.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
            $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        } else {
            $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        }
    } );
```

and here is what i added

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("button").on("click", function () {
    jQuery( ".menu-primary-nav-container" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
});
```

Template link: https://twentythirteendemo.wordpress.com/

Comment: Got a clue: `.toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );` but not sliding

Comment: Do you mean `.menu-main-nav-container`? I don't see a `.menu-primary-nav-container` class.

Comment: @litel see 2013 link it have a class inside menu

Comment: Toggle button has already script implemented and your click event comes second, hope you get it.

Comment: @Erik S I don't see the class of `menu-main-nav-container` anywhere on your page. There's a `ul` tag with the id `primary-menu` inside—is that what you mean?

Comment: @litel Check under `<a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>`

Comment: The CSS I see on that line is `<div class="menu-main-nav-container">`

Answer (score 0):

That template already has script assigned to click event and it toggles the class `toggled-on` on the menu list (and that is the reason you see no sliding). What you need to do is to disable new class this way:

```
.toggled-on .nav-menu, .toggled-on .nav-menu > ul {
    display: none; /* It was block */
}
```

Comment: added but no sliding effect.

Comment: I've tested it on the template you pointed above and it works. Please make sure your styles come after WP.